# Feynman diagrams related to Hedin's equations and OEIS A286784

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, many-body, self-energy

OEIS [A286784](https://oeis.org/A286784) contains the lower triangular matrix

1;

1,    1;

2,    4,      1;

5,    15,     9,      1;

14,    56,    56,     16,     1;

... ,

with elements $T_{n,k}$ (initialized with $n=k=0$) which enumerate, according to the entry, "the number of Feynman's diagrams with $k$ fermionic loops in the order $n$ of the perturbative expansion in dimension zero for the GW approximation of the self-energy function in a many-body theory of fermions with two-body interaction." The entry references "[Hedin's equations and enumeration of Feynman's diagrams](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0401500)" by Molinari.

Does anyone have explicit graphs of the first few Feynman diagrams?

A refinement of the matrix has popped up in some algebraic combinatorics related to dual methods of compositional inversion I've explored, and I wonder if the Feynman diagrams also indicate such a refinement based on their topology.

Comment: Explicit diagrams have been hand drawn and  given to me by the author Luca Molinari. I'll post an answer to this Q here when I have completed, probably this week, a set of notes on the broader context of this array.